# fetch email and display on android textview

Tags: java, android, web-services, textview, fetch

I have to develop one android application.

Here i have to fetch the email for beloning user and display that email on android textview.how can i develop these.please give me any idea.

This is my webservice code:

```
public class Login {
  public String authentication(String username,String password){

       String retrievedUserName = "";
       String retrievedPassword = "";
       String retrievedEmail = "";
       String status = "";
       try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xcart-432pro","root","");
       PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM xcart_customers WHERE login = '"+username+"'");
         ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
         while(result.next()){  
          retrievedUserName = result.getString("login");
          retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");
          retrievedEmail = result.getString("email");   
           }
         if(retrievedUserName.equals(username)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password)&&!(retrievedUserName.equals("") && retrievedPassword.equals(""))){
         status = retrievedEmail;
           }

       else {
        status = "Login fail!!!";
          }

            }

          catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
            }
         return status;

             }

              }
```

Here i have to run these webservice code means if login is success means have  displayed email id successfully.if my login is incorrect means have displayed login failed message.so my webservice code is correct.

If my login is success means have to display email on android textview.otherwise have to display login failed message.

But here i have faced one problem:

If i have enter correct login detail means thats time also have displayed login failed message.but i have to need the o/p like if my login sucess means display email otherwise login failed message.

Whats wrong in my code.please give me solution for these.

This is my android side code:

```
    public class CustomerLogin extends Activity {
    private static final String SPF_NAME = "vidslogin";
    private static final String USERNAME = "login";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
   private static final String PREFS_NAME = null;


         private String login;
       String mGrandTotal,total,mTitle,mTotal,mQty,mCost;

      EditText username,userPassword;
      private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
      private final String URL = "http://10.0.0.75:8085/XcartLogin/services/Login?wsdl";
      private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/authentication";
      private final String METHOD_NAME = "authentication";
      private String uName;

         /**Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.customer_login);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
        userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);

         Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
         login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View arg0) {
          loginAction();

          }
         });
          }
          private void loginAction(){


             SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
                 String user_Name = username.getText().toString();
              EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
               String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

                 //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
               PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
               unameProp.setName("username");//Define the variable name in the web service method
               unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
        unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
        request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

      //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
        PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
        passwordProp.setName("password");
        passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
        passwordProp.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(passwordProp);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try{
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
               SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
               String status = response.toString();
               TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
               email.setText(response.toString());

               if(status.equals(email))
               {


if(isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated)
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerLogin.this,PayPalIntegrationActivity.class);


  startActivity(intent);

      }
       }

                       else
                          {

                           LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                           View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_custom_layout,
                                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
                          Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                          toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 30);
                          toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                          toast.setView(layout);
                          toast.show();

                          }
                         }
              catch(Exception e){

                  }
                 }

          }
```

**EDIT:**

Here i have wrote the code like means

```
               if(status.equals("krishnaveniveeman@gmail.com"))
```

am getting the email in textview after enter the correct login deatils.

Here how can i fetch the email from webservice and also set the email on textview.

I have to writhe code like

```
                   if(status.equals(email))
```

means the login failed message only displayed.but my login detail is correct only.

please anyone give me solution for these.

Comment: You want email id registered with phone right??

Comment: @Changdeo Jadhav no ya...i have retrieve email from mysql server and display on android textview via soap calling.